# Tracking corners of a moving rotating rectangle c++ openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Basically I have a car (rectangle) that moves in 2d space.
Tracking the corners for basic collision detection with other objects.
I can't figure my trigonometry out properly.
Currently I have the following:

```
this->FL.x = this->position.x - this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180) + this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180);
this->FL.y = this->position.z + this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180) - this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180); 
this->FR.x = this->position.x + this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180) + this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180);
this->FR.y = this->position.z + this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180) + this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180); 
this->BL.x = this->position.x - this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180) - this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180); 
this->BL.y = this->position.z - this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180) - this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180); 
this->BR.x = this->position.x + this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180) - this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180); 
this->BR.y = this->position.z - this->C_length/2*sin(this->spinY*pi/180) + this->C_width/2*cos(this->spinY*pi/180);
```

Comment: you're using opengl as I see, then if you rotate/move it with matrices, you can get the coords of the box too with them on cpu.

Comment: It matters really little, I know, but is there really need for all of those `this->` prefixes? Your code is extremely unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

Not the easiest way but the always correct one is to use the MODEL matrix that places your object in the scene and multiply the positions of the corners with that. This will take care of translation/rotations/scaling and their interactions for you.

In OpenGL you have MODELVIEW matrix. That is the Model matrix multiplied with the view matrix (or the camera). You can either recompute the model matrix (any matrix lib will help you here). Or multiply the MODELVIEW with the inverted VIEW matrix. You can get them with glGetMatrix.